# Rendering image is just black?

Tags: camera, lighting

Im making a model of a creature for school and when i render its just black. How can i see my object? Image #1 is what my image should look like when i render it:[image]

but this is what im getting when im rendering:[image]

Comment: If you press 0 on your numerical keyboard, what do you see? That will show the camera view. Perhaps you are not directing your camera to the object or you do not have lighting setup correctly.

Comment: Your camera may be "stuck" inside another object or zoomed in to far. You can always add a new camera.

Comment: Thanks, how do i add a new camera? and i clicked 0 and it was inside of my monsters body.

Comment: omg my camera is in the opposite direction, let me turn it around and see if that works

Comment: @Sprad001 here is what my cam looks like http://prntscr.com/mb4p22

Comment: @rob http://prntscr.com/mb4p22

Comment: By adding a new camera you should get all the camera settings reset then you can go to the View menu and Set Active Object as Camera.